# How to Store videos online and stream them

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, upload, video-streaming, cloud

How to **store a large amount of videos online** and enable users to **stream** them, so how can i **use cloud services** to do so.

The website admin will upload many videos per month and users will be able to stream and watch them, so i'm expecting a quite good/heavy traffic, you can say it will be like Vimeo or YouTube but smaller scale of course.

So the requirement:

- Store as many video file as i want.
- Users can stream without bandwidth/traffic limitation (buying service is okay)
- Full control of the uploaded storage (edit & delete).
- Web statistics (streaming, visitors, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do some research into [CloudFront media streaming](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/). You might also want to look into [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) for conversion of uploaded videos into the proper formats.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it :)